# How to use FacetWP to search on category branches?

Tags: wordpress, faceted-search, facetwp

I'm working on a website where I have posts that have multiple categories and subcategories assigned to them. Now I want to use FacetWP to give users the option to search these posts on their categories and subcategories. I want it to work hierarchical as the following example.

Say one post has the following categories assigned to it:

```
France  - Paris   - River
                  - Street
        - Lyon    - Street
                  - House
Germany - Hamburg - Street
        - Berlin  - House
                  - Church
```

Now I want to create dropdown facets, where I want the first dropdown to offer only the main categories (countries in this case). After that, when someone has selected a country, I want a second dropdown to only show the sub-categories of that particular country (cities in this case). After that, I want the next dropdown to only show the sub-sub-categories.

So, when someone selects France, the next dropdown should only show Paris and Lyon (not Hamburg and Berlin). When Paris gets selected, the next dropdown should only show River and Street (not also House or Church)

Is this possible with FacetWP? Or is there a way to tweak it to make it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create 3 facets, one for each category level.

Then you will have to use the `facetwp_facet_html` filter.

Here is an example, where I use the [select2 facet](https://github.com/FacetWP/facetwp-select2):

```

```
function fwp_limit_subcategory( $output, $params ) {

  $facet = $params['facet'];
  if ($facet['type'] != 'select2') { return $output; }

  $custom_out = $out = '';
  $exploded = explode('<option', $output);


if ( 'subcategory' == $facet['name'] ) {

    // See if a category is selected
    foreach ( FWP()->facet->facets as $f ) {

        if ( 'category' == $f['name'] && empty( $f['selected_values'] ) ) {
          return $exploded[0].'</select>';
        }

        if ( 'category' == $f['name'] && ! empty( $f['selected_values'] ) ) {

            $term_slugs = $f['selected_values'];

            foreach($term_slugs as $term_slug) {

              $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, 'category' );
              if ( isset( $term->term_id ) ) {

                  $get_terms = get_terms(
                    array(
                      'parent' => $term->term_id, 
                      'taxonomy' => 'category',
                      'hierarchical' => true
                    )
                  );
                  foreach ($exploded as $opt) {
                    foreach($get_terms as $child) {
                      if (strpos($opt, $child->slug) !== false) {
                        $custom_out .= '<option '. $opt;
                      }
                    }

                  }



              }
            }

        }
    }
  }
}

if ($custom_out != '') { 
  $out .= $exploded[0].$custom_out;
  if (strpos($out, '</select>') === false) {
    $out .= '</select>';
  }
  return $out; 


return $output;

}
add_filter( 'facetwp_facet_html', 'fwp_limit_subcategory', 10, 2 );
```

```

I hope this helped you and put you on the right track.

**EDIT**

I have discovered an additional solution that may also be of help.

1. [Index top only categories in one facet](https://facetwp.com/index-only-top-level-taxonomy-terms/)
2. [Index child only categories in another facet](https://facetwp.com/index-only-child-taxonomy-terms/)
3. [Tweak the results of the second facet according to the result of the first one](https://gist.github.com/mgibbs189/8d2df374e7b2636bbba42528843a4e16)
4. Repeat for third, fourth facet etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used another solution. I used the hierarchy facet and it sort of did enough to solve my problem.